# Is my proof of closedness of multiplication operator corect?

Tags: integration, proof-verification, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

I am considering an operator $A: L^2(\mathbb R , d \mu)  \supset D(A)\to L^2 (\mathbb R, d\mu)$ defined by $(Af)(x)=a(x)f(x)$ for known measurable function $a$. Domain is of course all those functions for which result is square integrable. I want to (directly) show that it is closed, that is its graph is closed subset of $L^2 \oplus L^2$. I want to make sure my proof is correct. I consider an element of closure $(f,g)$. Then there is a sequence $  f_n  \in D(A)$ converging to $f$ such that $af_n $ converges to g. I choose subsequence of $f_n$ that converges pointwise a.e. (and denote it like original sequence from now on). Then $af_n$ converges pointwise a.e. to $af$. However we also know that its subsequence converges pointwise a.e. to $g$ which is square integrable. Since sequence can have only one limit point we deduce that those functions are equal almost everywhere, which means that $f \in D(A)$. I use similar arguments to show that $A$ is closable, which combined with statement above shows it's closed. If above is not correct I will appreciate hints how to fix it. I'm also curious about alternative methods.

Comment: You need to get rid of the absolute value signs, from $\lvert af_n\rvert \to \lvert af\rvert$ (a.e.), you cannot deduce $g = af$. But you can choose a subsequence of $(f_n)$ that converges pointwise a.e. to $f$, so the absolute value signs aren't necessary.

Comment: Daniel, I only needed to show that some functions are integrable so absolute values don't matter.

Comment: And now I have checked that I could have dropped the absolute value signs. Somehow I thought that theorem I used worked for L^1 and not all L^p so I worked around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(f,af) \in \mathcal{G}(A)$ iff $\sqrt{1+|a|^{2}}f \in L^{2}_{\mu}$. Furthermore, for any such $f$,
$$
               \|(f,af)\|_{\mathcal{G}(A)}=\|\sqrt{1+|a|^{2}}f\|_{L^{2}_{\mu}}=\|f\|_{L^{2}_{d\nu}},
$$
where $d\nu = \sqrt{1+|a|^{2}}d\mu$. So the graph is a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you, this is obviously clearer and faster way than mine and actually helped me in another exercise :) But do you maybe know if my proof is correct?

Comment: @Blazej : Yes, your proof looks good to me. Because I wanted to answer, I decided to give you an alternative approach. :)